# Rolling back Apple Watch G0

Tags: apple-watch

I have a 0th gen Apple Watch, which is getting incredibly slow these days. Is there any way I can roll this back to older WatchOS, even WatchOS 1?

Answer (score 1):

No, there's no way to downgrade Apple Watch software to earlier releases.